# How to use toEqual(...) with AngularJS promise data?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

When authoring AngularJS resource factories via [the `$resource` service in the `ngResource` module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), the return values of the action methods are objects with additional properties `$promise` and `$resolve`.  What is the preferred way to strip or ignore those properties so that they can be compared to sample data using [the Jasmine `toEqual(..)` matcher](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers)?

For example, I might have specs that look like this:

```javascript
describe('the #query() action method', function() {
  var mockData;
  beforeEach(function() {
    mockData = [1, 2, 3];
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/foo').respond(200, JSON.stringify(mockData));
  });
  it('returns the mock data', function() {
    var queryData = MyResource.query();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(queryData).toEqual(mockData);
    // ^-- Fails since "queryData" has properties $resource and $resolve.
  });
});
```

Currently I am working around by inserting the following line before calling the matcher but this feels like a kludge:

```
queryData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(queryData));
```

Is there a better/preferred way to compare promise data which ignores the added properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to solve this is by adding a matcher. For example:

```
  beforeEach(function(){
    this.addMatchers({
      toEqualData: function(expected) {
        return angular.equals(this.actual, expected);
      }
    });
  });
```

angular.equals ignores functions when it compares objects. 
Now you can use:

```
expect(queryData).toEqualData(mockData);
```

Full explanation of this exact solution can be found [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/tutorial/step_11)